# Angular 4: Order By Array of Dates

Tags: angular, sorting, date, typescript

I have got a problem regarding sorting an array of Dates in Angular 4. I want to order my `Customer`
array by the value `releaseDate`. So this is what I have right now:

In the `customer.component.ts` :

```
sort() {
    this.customers.sort((a: Customer, b: Customer) =>
      new Date(a.releaseDate).getTime() - new Date (b.releaseDate).getTime());
  }
```

I want to trigger this method by clicking on a button in `customer.component.html`:

```
<button (click)="sort()"> Sort</button>
<li *ngFor="let customer of customers">
  {{customer.releaseDate}}
</li>
```

When I click the button nothing happens. The Array stays the same and I also don't get an error message.

Am I missing something? Can anyone help?

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer (thank you). But if you solved the problem could you perhaps add an edit section to your question to explain what the problem was (since both JeanPaulA and myself think your code is correct but your data not correct). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the plunker that @JeanPaul A created so you can see the difference. In his plunker he is updating the array itself, not objects inside the array, so I think it needed updating.

If you look at the [new plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HRsqfGqLHt7QqjdVqif7?p=preview) you can see the difference, but it does work, sorting the objects inside the array. I think there must be something wrong with your data. I added the DatePipe to format the dates so you can use this to easily see in the UI that your dates are correct.

**Plunkr Code:**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="sort()">Sort</button>
      <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let date of dates">{{date | date: 'dd MM yyyy'}}</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let customer of customers">
         {{customer.name}} -
         {{customer.releaseDate | date: 'dd MM yyyy'}}</li>
      </ul>      
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  customers: Array<any> = [
    {"name": 'Mickey', "releaseDate": new Date('2012-07-12')},
    {"name": 'Minnie', "releaseDate": new Date('2013-07-12')},
    {"name": 'Donald', "releaseDate": new Date('2010-07-12')},
    {"name": 'Pluto', "releaseDate": new Date('2014-07-12')}
    ]

  dates:Array<Date> = [
    new Date('2012-07-12'),
    new Date('2013-07-12'),
    new Date('2010-07-12'),
    new Date('2014-07-12')
  ];
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  sort() {
    this.dates.sort((a:Date, b:Date) => new Date(a).getTime() - new Date (b).getTime());
    this.customers.sort((a: Customer, b: Customer) =>
      new Date(a.releaseDate).getTime() - new Date (b.releaseDate).getTime());
    console.log(this.customers);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: @JeanPaulA. Thanks, but I couldn't have done it without your code! :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax which you are using is very much correct, and how it should be.

[Here's a](https://plnkr.co/edit/PFhP32EFauclEo1QGA2n?p=preview) working plunker demonstrating exactly what you are doing.

Most probably the problem is related to the value of `releaseDate` that you are using to construct the `Date` object. What is the output of a console.log in the sort function?

Comment: The output is an Array of dates in the format like this one: 1520290800000

Comment: That's very odd... it should work if the data is correct... Could you update your question with a sample of the data you are trying to sort?